# Как исправить JS скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт с якорем рабочий, привязан к менюшке карты, при выборе другого элемента или повторном клике экран дергается, как можно исправить?

```js
function scrollToMap() {
 var map = $('.geography--contacts');
 var buttons = $('.geography__area--target').add('.geography__target');

 if ( $('.page').outerWidth() <= 768 ) {
  map = $('.geography__map');
 }

 buttons.on('click', function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: map.offset().top - 100
  }, 500);
 });

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте проверить в событии клика, расстояние до верха страницы, сейчас оно в любом случае пытается выполнить анимацию, даже если расстояние уже в конечном положении

Comment: Ну я об этом и думал, но я только учусь, не знаю как такую проверку сделать